# syntax of join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to know the syntax of joins in sql so please help regarding this

thanks

Comment: `SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;`

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Hi,check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Example query:

```
SELECT u.id, m.phone_number
FROM user u
JOIN meta m ON u.id=m.user_id;
```

Keep in mind that `JOIN` defaults to an inner join in MySQL.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)'s a helpful visualisation of the several types of joins, with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

[Read This Demo queries](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

"Orders" and "Cusomers" are your tables, with some fields. 
That's an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Those are the types and their meanings:

INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables

LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table

RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table

FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

(w3schools.com reference)